# C++ Designing a event handler class

Tags: c++

I've been working on designing a library. One of the aspect is going to be a `EventManager`.

So far the design go like this:

```
Client client
client.on(string, function);
```

Where string is a `std::string` and function is a `std::function<void()>`
`client.on` is defined as such:

```
void Client::on(const std::string& name, const std::function<void()>& function) {
    _eventManager->add(string, function);
}
```

And `_eventManager->add(string, function)` only objective is to create a struct called `Event` and store the name and function in it and then push the new strut to a vector.

Now I can do something similar to this:
`_eventManager->emit("test");`
It will then loop the vector array and find any `event.name` that is equal to the name you use when you called `emit` and run the function within that struct.

This all work and is pretty great and awesome and all, however it isn't exactly what I need and will not work because I need to send a second argument with `_eventManager->emit()`. The second argument is going be unknown, well not unknown but it can be a multiple data type based on the string you enter in the first argument.

Example usage:

```
Client client();

client.on("ready", [](User user) {
    user.test();
});

User user;
_eventManager->emit("ready", user); //I know this does not exists but it is nearly an example.

client.on("message_created", [](Message message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl; //Operator overload here
}

Message message("Something to print");

_eventManager->emit("message_created", message));
```

I thought about using `boost::variant` to allow the multiple types to be allow being passed, however you would have to retrieve them by doing something like so within the function.

```
client.on("ready", [](boost::variant<User, Message> args){
    User user = boost::get<User>(args);
});
```

And it is suppose to be simple too, I rather not have the person using the library forced to use `boost::get` within all the events to retrieve the class that get passed.

That's being said, with all the wonderful information above, what would be another alternative for what I want to do? Any suggestions on why I should or shouldn't do what I am doing?

This took me a long time to write so thank you in advanced and I hope all of this make sense.

Comment: Why not just use an existing library like [Qt](https://www.qt.io), [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org), [gtk](https://www.gtk.org) or similar? Why go through the pain of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Your `on` function template knows the argument type accepted by the callback. It can instantiate an intermediate thunk which takes a variant, extracts the expected type, and (if successful) calls the original callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution which uses variable templates (C++14), but it looks like a horrible hack. One disadvantage of it is that variable templates can only be static. Assuming you can live with it (though it's already bad)...

For each type of message (here type = list of parameters passed to the handler), you are going to have a separate list of handlers. This can be implemented like this:

```
template<typename F> static map<string, vector<F>> list;
```

Here an example for `F` is `void(int)` - a function that receives one `int` argument. Another example is `void(int, int)` - a function that receives two `int` arguments. The data structure I use here stores a `vector` of handlers for each message name. I could alternatively use `multimap`.

When "registering" an event handler, just add it to the list of handlers:

```
template<typename F> static void add_handler(string s, F f)
{
    list<F>[s].push_back(f);
}
```

When looking up the event handlers, you should specify their type explicitly. This is a crucial part, which implements type safety - it will lookup only in the data structure that corresponds to the type of the called handler.

```
template<typename F, typename... A> static void call_handlers(string s, A... args)
{
    for (F f: list<F>[s])
        f(args...);
}
```

---

Usage:

```
// Define event handlers
// Their type SHOULD be explicit (not lambda), because we will reference it further
function<void(int)> action1 = [](int k){cout << "notify user " << k << '\n';};
function<void(int)> action2 = [](int k){cout << "alert user " << k << '\n';};
function<void(int, int)> action3 = [](int a, int b){cout << "give $" << a << " to user " << b << '\n';};

// Register the handlers
add_handler("good_event", action1);
add_handler("good_event", action2);
add_handler("bad_event", action2);
add_handler("money_event", action3);

// Generate events, which will call the handlers
call_handlers<function<void(int)>>("good_event", 7);
call_handlers<function<void(int)>>("bad_event", 8);
call_handlers<function<void(int, int)>>("money_event", 100, 9);

// Wrong call, but no compilation error - the handler is just not found
call_handlers<function<void(int)>>("money_event", 99);
```